# undefined local variable or method `play' for #<PlaysController:0xae60660>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

undefined local variable or method `play' for #

Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

```
def new

    @play = play.new
end
def create
```

Rails.root: C:/broadway

class PlaysController < ApplicationController
    def index

```
end
def new

    @play = play.new
end
def create

    @play = play.new(play_params)

end
private

def play_params
    params.require(:play).permit(:title, :description, :director)

end
```

end

Comment: Capitalize your model names correctly. It's probably `Play`, rather than `play`.

Answer (score 0):

The classname is `Play` and not `play`.

```
def new
  @play = Play.new
end

def create
  @play = Play.new(play_params)
end
```